Hot do I get rid of satellite trails on astrophotos?
I tried to photograph the Northern Crown constellation last night (2024-05-10 23:40 UTC), but it was crossed by satellites several times:


Here are the parameters of both pictures: 24 mm, f/4, 10 sec, ISO 2500
Camera: Canon EOS 70D (astromodified) + Canon EF 24–105 mm f/4 L IS USM
Position: 53.06414° N, 8.22809 W.
As I'd like to stack several pictures without the trails, how can I get rid of them quickly without throwing away relevant parts of the picture? Does Siril or another astrophoto software offer some kinda trail removal routine?

I really don't want to be that guy, but have you tried Google?  I searched for "remove satellite trails from photos" and came up with a whole lot of solutions.

If you are stacking several photos and the trails are more or less random, wouldn't they get suppressed in the averaging process?

I wonder if the trails show up if you stacked the images. Ideally anything that is only present in one frame is removed anyway.
